# Multiple LEFT OUT JOINs in Linq to Sql

Tags: linq-to-sql, c#-4.0

I have the following structure of tables:

Items 
 - ItemId
 - ItemTypeId

ItemTypes 
 - ItemTypeId

ItemTypes_Locale 
 - ItemTypeId
 - Id
 - Name

What I need to do is create a Linq to SQL query to return:

Items.ItemId, ItemTypes_Locale.Name

Is that doable with LEFT OUTER JOINs?

Thanks

Comment: I played around with LinqPad and created something as: <p>
 
 from li in ListingItems
  from t in RealEstateTypes
     .Where(t => t.RealEstateTypeId == li.RealEstateTypeId).DefaultIfEmpty()
  from tLocale in RealEstateTypes_Locale
     .Where(tLocale => tLocale.RealEstateTypeId == t.RealEstateTypeId && tLocale.CultureId == 1).DefaultIfEmpty()
 select new {li.ListingItemId, RealEstateType = tLocale.Name}

Answer (score 0):

I played around with LinqPad and created something as:

```
from item in Items
from t in ItemTypes
     .Where(t => t.ItemTypeId == item.ItemTypeId).DefaultIfEmpty()
from tLocale in ItemTypes_Locale
     .Where(tLocale => tLocale.ItemTypeId == t.ItemTypeId).DefaultIfEmpty()
select new 
  {
     item.ItemId, 
     ItemType = tLocale.Name
  }
```

Thanks